# Drag and Drop - Is it possible to get the URL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I implemented a simple drag and drop. The main purpose is for users to drag and drop images from a browser. Is it possible for me get the URL that this image was dragged from?

So lets say, I am on SO and I drag and drop the logo. Is there a way for me to know that this was from http://stackoverflow.com ?
Thanks

Comment: Nice question, but I suspect that if you don't see any URL in the incoming drag, there'd be no way to query the browser where that image came from.  This is something that each browser manufacturer (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) would have to provide in their drag implementations.  Maybe file enhancement requests into Radar (for Safari) and Bugzilla (for Firefox)?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is it at least possible to know what app the drag came from?

Comment: No, it isn't. That is not passed as part of the dragging information.

Comment: Dang. Just spent hours trying to figure this out and going through all the apple documentation. For me, i just want to re-upload the dragged image from web, so that is possible. would be AMAZING to get url though! :( i think the EXIF metadata option would work sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

For images which aren't also links, the following code will log the URL a dragged image came from. This works for me in Safari & Firefox.

```
@implementation DragView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType]];
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard;    
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    NSLog(@"types: %@", [pboard types]);
    NSLog(@"url: %@", [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard]);

    return YES;
}

@end
```

If the image is also a link, the logged URL is a href of that link. It's also possible to get the "where from" URL from a file (as seen in the Finder's Get Info panel) using the kMDItemWhereFroms key of the extended attributes.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't want the URL of the image. I want the URL of the webpage it was dragged from.

Comment: Aaaah! I can't help you with that then, sorry!