# Finding the origin (URL) of a dragged and dropped image/text on a cocoa application dock tile on 10.6.8

Tags: cocoa, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop, dock

I have just started coding an application in cocoa on OSX 10.6.8. It is well underway mostly thanks to threads I have found here. For the subtle functionality I am about to explain I've looked everywhere and really have given it my best without success. Here is the situation:

- There is a browser (chrome for now but the solution should be adaptable to FF and Safari at least)
- There is my chrome extension
- There is my desktop app
- Text/images can be dragged on my desktop app which then organises these items by source.

  For a file/text from finder, except a web browser, tagging the file with its file path is the desired behaviour, for a text I simply put clipboard as the source. Now the issue is that files/text dragged from a web browser should have the website they were dragged from as the source. There is an easy fix for files: I have an extension which sets a buffer with the last active url so that all I need to check when a file is dragged is whether it comes from the chrome cache to tag it with the content of the said buffer. My problem is for text. The way text dragging is handled is by [using a service which I declared in the .plist](http://lethain.com/cocoa-drag-and-drop-text-into-the-dock-icon/), There is a [similar unanswered question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554170/mac-osx-cocoa-setting-up-app-to-recieve-dragged-items-from-another-app-to-w) and a [technique that seems as if it could work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203402/drag-and-drop-is-it-possible-to-get-the-url) but it is only available for 10.7 on. I also found a link where someone managed to get the url for itunes songs dragged on his application using http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg17452.html

Is there a solution to see the URL of a dragged image/text that could be handled using only cocoa?
The only other option I see is using the extension to inject javascript code into all webpages for handling the 'dragenter' event and send the content of what is being dragged together with the source URL to the desktop app via a custom protocol. I'm not too keen on script injection and I sense some complication down that path as well.

In any case thank you for your help!

Chocozor.